# grails 4 unit test controller could not find class

Tags: testing, grails, groovy

I am using grails 4 to create unit test for controller
https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html

My controller is under grails-app/controllers/mypack/myfolder/exampleController.groovy

My unit test is under src/test/groovy/mypack/myfolder/exampleControllerSpec.groovy

my unit test is like this
class exampleControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest< exampleController>

but it complain can not resolve symbol 'exampleController'

anything wrong here?

how to import exampleController

Comment: Which symbol cannot be resolved, and do you have import statements for all of the classes/traits/interfaces mentioned by name in your source file?

Comment: can not resolve symbol 'exampleController', looks like it can not find the controller groovy, how can I import the groovy controller?

Comment: "how can I import the groovy controller" - Controllers are imported just like any other class.  However, in your case since the test and the controller are in the same package an import statement should not be needed.  Is the first line of code in both `grails-app/controllers/mypack/myfolder/exampleController.groovy` and `src/test/groovy/mypack/myfolder/exampleControllerSpec.groovy` look like `package mypack.myfolder`?  Separate from that, class names that begin with a lower case letter (like `exampleController` and `exampleControllerSpec`) are considered a violations of best practice.

Comment: yes, both start package same: package package-path , controller is under grails-app/controllers/package-path/, unit test is under src/test/groovy/package-path/

Comment: The original question mentions `src/test/groovy/mypack/myfolder/exampleControllerSpec.groovy` and also mentions `DemoControllerSpec`.   Have you defined a class named `DemoControllerSpec` in a file named `exampleControllerSpec.groovy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/leecontrollertest demonstrates how to construct the test.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/leecontrollertest/blob/d6fc272a69406f71286bf5268794ef4a4252a15b/grails-app/controllers/mypack/myfolder/exampleController.groovy

```
package mypack.myfolder

// NOTE: The nonstandard class naming convention here is intentional
// per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723769/grails-4-unit-test-controller-could-not-find-class
class exampleController {

    def hello() {
        render 'Hello, World!'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/leecontrollertest/blob/d6fc272a69406f71286bf5268794ef4a4252a15b/src/test/groovy/mypack/myfolder/exampleControllerSpec.groovy

```
package mypack.myfolder

import grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

// NOTE: The nonstandard class naming convention here is intentional
// per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723769/grails-4-unit-test-controller-could-not-find-class
class exampleControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<exampleController> {

    void "test action which renders text"() {
        when:
        controller.hello()

        then:
        status == 200
        response.text == 'Hello, World!'
    }
}
```